# Mechanal Damage to Front End Suspension

Tags: toyota, suspension, camry

I took my car to an Auto Repair Shop to have the two front end control arms replaced on a 2005 Toyota Camry XLE. The the repair shop stripped the nut located in the sub-frame on the driver side. As a result they drilled a hole through the sub frame with a nut and bolt to hold the control arm in place.

Questions:

1. What type of structural damage so this do to the vehicle?
2. If the nut was difficult to remove does it require a specialized set of tools and a high level of expertise to be repaired properly.
3. What type of hazard could this create when operating the vehicle?

Comment: I hope they just drilled the bolt out, not drilled another hole to hold the control arm in place? Latter sounds like gross incompetence and likely not even physically possible.

Comment: Without pictures of the repair we are guessing what they actually did.

Answer (score 1):

The risk here is that the suspension may come apart while the car is being driven.

1. The repair could have done minimal structural damage the car, or significant structural damage. Without physically examining the work, or at least seeing good-quality photographs, it's impossible to answer your first question.
2. No. This is within the capability of a competent mechanic. That the job could not handled without drilling new holes in the car demonstrates that the mechanic who worked on the car was not competent.
3. Like the answer to #1, it's impossible to say. This work might create no hazard, or it might create a terrible hazard to the occupants and other drivers and pedestrians who are close by.

You should have the car looked at immediately by another mechanic.